# Investment analysis software

Tags: investing, software, recommendation, online-applications

I'm looking for software for investment analysis. It should be able to calculate and visualize:

- NPV

  - Net present value of an investment after 3, 5, 10 years
- IRR

  - Internal rate of return
- ROI

  - Return on investment: profit compared to bank interest
- BEP

  - Break-even point: when invested capital is returned

Is there any software to calculate and visualize the above conveniently by getting intuitive inputs?

Comment: This would be a pretty simple spreadsheet …

Comment: @quid Well, just curious, if that's so simple, there should be some app to make it convenient and user-friendly. Right?

Comment: I guess, but unfortunately product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: I have a tool based on Aswath Damodaran's spreadsheets to make it simpler. The end goal is to allow all the stuff you want. tracktak.com if you are interested.

Comment: @MartinDawson Thanks! Looks promising =)

Comment: This [Excel template](https://www.someka.net/excel-template/npv-irr-calculator/) might be helpful.

Comment: Also, there is [this spreadsheet template](https://www.vertex42.com/Calculators/npv-irr-calculator.html).